# Can't get calendar to display

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this function that will call JavaScript code that shows a calendar when I click on a text field:

```
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
};
```

and there is the first calling of the function on first textfield which works fine:

```
<input name="PickDate" type="text" id="inputField" readonly="readonly"/>
```

but when I call the same function on the same page it's not working at all and nothing appears.  This how I call the function, since I think the problem is with how I'm calling it:

```
<input name="PickReturnDate" type="text" id="inputField" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: where are you calling the function=??

Comment: i am calling the function through id

Comment: Are you really using the same ID for two elements?

Comment: sadlly yes but i did know that wrong man but how i can do it ??

Comment: i need to use this function in same page twice and i cant use same id :S any way out ?

Answer (score 2):

Your target is `target:"inputField"`, that's why first one is working and next one is not.

Comment: sorry man that's was typing mistake i did enter same ID for both and its not work :S

Comment: you cannot use same id for both the controls. Id must be different

Comment: uh  very nice maaaan i expected that's but how i am able to solve it ?!! all function as i know can called more and more but here is where you cant call function twice :P

Comment: create two similar func one for first input and another for second input. Change the target

Comment: ummm sorry for that but isn't it stupid ?!! in case i want do that more than two times ?!!! :S

Comment: since you are specifying the target control id directly , so i think there no way out.

Comment: and its not work i think coz the "inputField" is used in the javascript file i use and if i made new function wtith new keywords like "inputField2" it wont be work

Comment: i did call the function by this way onclick javascript: function('value') but its not work :((

Comment: its works on this site :(((((((   http://www.avis.com/car-rental/avisHome/home.ac

Comment: It works on that site because the input fields have different ids.

Comment: okay so how i am able to do it ?? :S please i tried alot and its not work i cant made new function and use its new id because i shoud change the whole javascript :S

Comment: @Sparky: can't achieve it i am beginner in programing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        new JsDatePick ({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField1",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
        new JsDatePick ({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField2",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
    };
</script>

<td><input type="text" size="12" name="dob" id="inputField1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="doj" id="inputField1" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ´target´.Because the id of you input is inputField2 not inputfield.

```
 window.onload = function(){
   new JsDatePick({
    useMode:2,
    target:"inputField2",
    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
   });
};
```

Comment: soryy man it was typing mistake the id are same in two calling     target:"inputField",

Comment: man as dotneto said i cannot use same id for both the controls. Id must be different so any ideas how to sovle this ???